# Add file name to Copy activity in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, sink, azure-data-factory

I want to copy data from a CSV file (`Source`) on Blob storage to Azure SQL Database table (`Sink`) via regular `Copy activity` but I want to copy also file name alongside every entry into the table. I am new to ADF so the solution is probably easy but I have not been able to find the answer in the documentation and neither on the internet so far.

My mapping currently looks like this (I have created a table for output with the `file name` column but this data is not explicitly defined at the column level at the CSV file therefore I need to extract it from the metadata and pair it to the column):
[image: Image of the mapping from Azure Data Factory]

For the first time, I thought that I am going to put `dynamic content` in there and therefore solve the problem this way. But there is not an option to use dynamic content in each individual box so I do not know how to implement the solution. My next thought was to use `Pre-copy script` but have not seen how could I use it for this purpose. What is the best way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Mapping columns of copy activity you cannot add the dynamic content of Meta data.

First give the source csv dataset to the **Get Metadata activity** then join it with copy activity like below.

[image]

You can add the file name column by the **Additional columns** in the copy activity source itself by giving the **`dynamic content of the Get Meta data Actvity`** after giving same source csv dataset.

```
@activity('Get Metadata1').output.itemName
```

[image]

If you are sure about the data types of your data then no need to go to the mapping, you can execute your pipeline.

Here I am copying the contents of **samplecsv.csv** file to SQL table named **output**.

[image]

My output for your reference:

[image]